# wxgrid: set grid columns on every run

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxgrid

An application outputs it's result to a table created using wx.grid.Application runs by clicking on a button on the UI. I want to make result go to its corresponding row in wxgrid on every run. Table for the first run looks as below

[image]
Below is the piece of code to set all the columns of first row for the first run.

```
out = [value,minvalue,maxvalue,actualvalue,Measuredvalue,result]
for row in range(1):
    for col in range(6):
        self.page2.grid.SetCellValue(row,col,"%s" % (out[col]))
```

Now, on the second run,result should be entered on row 'test2' and likewise for all runs. Please suggest a solution!

Comment: When you say "run", do you mean the application is closed between each run, and you want to save the data between runs?

Comment: Because if not, just use a variable to store the number of runs and properly set the row index.